# How do I add/remove text boxes with JQuery changing the variable name to keep the name attributes different?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a book catalog with JQuery to add books to a author. In the code That I have I am trying to add a author and have his books be in a array with his number only. Separated by other authors and their own arrays of books.

For example, when I press the button to add a author a input box appears so that I can add the authors name also a button to add a book that when I press that button I get an input box to add a books name.

[image: ex1]

When I press the add author again I want to be able to add another author with the same input boxes as before (adding more books to that author).

[image: ex2]

Also to add multiple books assigned to that author.

[image]

I have already done this in the pics but I get an array of everything. I want it to be separated by author.

author1 has an array of {book1, book2, book3...}

author2 has an array of {book13, book14, book15}

(i'm a beginner at JQuery)

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#main {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
        <form role="form" method="post">
            <p class="all_fields">

                <button class="add_author">Add Author</button>

                <div id="commonPart" class="commonPart">
                    <label for="author1">Author <span class="author-number">1</span></label>            
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="author" value="" id="author1" />
                    <br/>
                    <button class="add_book">Add book</button>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function($){
    var wrapper         = $(".all_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var commonPart      = $("#commonPart"); 
    var add_author      = $(".add_author"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton   = $(".add_book"); //Add sub button ID
    $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){

        var n = $('.all_fields').length + 1;
        if( 15 < n ) {
            alert('Stop it!');
            return false;
        }


    $(add_author).click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        var htmlToAdd = $('<label for="author' + n + '">Author <span class="author-number">' + n + '</span></label><br/><input type="text" name="author' + n + '" value="" id="author' + n + '" /><br/><button class="add_book">Add book</button><a class="add-book" href="#">Add Book</a><div><input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook' + n + '[]"/></div>');
        htmlToAdd.hide();
        $('.my-form p.all_fields:last').after(htmlToAdd);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });

    $(add_book).click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        var htmlToAdd = $('<div><input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook' + n + '[]"/></div>');
        htmlToAdd.hide();
        $('.my-form p.all_fields:last').after(htmlToAdd);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });

    $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
        $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you please edit it and make it understandable.

Comment: @A.J I added more info, I don't know if this is enough to explain it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated code(fixed some bugs..), try this....

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        #main {
         max-width: 800px;
         margin: 0 auto;
        }
        -->
       </style>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div id="main">
        <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
        <div class="my-form">
         <button onclick="addAuthor()" >Add Author</button><br><br>
         <div id="addAuth"></div>
         <br><br>
         <button onclick="submit()" >Submit</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id="result" ></div>
       </div>
       
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var authors = 0;
        function addAuthor(){
         authors++;
         var str = '<div id="auth'+authors+'"><input type="text" name="author" id="author'+authors+'" />'
            +'<button onclick="addMore(\'auth'+authors+'\')" >Add Book</button>'
            +'</div>';
         $("#addAuth").append(str);
        }
        
        var count=0;
        function addMore(id){
         count++;
         var str = '<div id="bookDiv'+count+'">'
           +'<input class="'+id+'" type="text" name="book'+id+'" />'
           +'<span onclick="addMore(\''+id+'\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: green; cursor:pointer;">+</span>'
           +'<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv'+count+'\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: red; cursor:pointer; margin-left:1%;">-</span>'
           +'</div>';
         $("#"+id).append(str);
        }
        
        function removeDiv(id){
         var val = confirm("Are you sure ..?");
         if(val){
          $("#"+id).slideUp(function(){$("#"+id).remove();});
         }
        }
        
        function submit(){
         var arr = [];
         for(i=1; i<=authors; i++){
          var obj = {};
          obj.name = $("#author"+i).val();
          obj.books = [];
          $(".auth"+i).each(function(){
           var data = $(this).val();
           obj.books.push(data);
          });
          
          arr.push(obj);
         }
         
         $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
        }
       </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: How do I add more authors with their books
`author1 {book1, book2, book3}
author2 {book4, book5}
author3 {book6, book7, book8}`

Comment: How would I send the data arr to a database? @Divesh

Comment: I've been trying to pass the array into a mysql database but I can't seem to figure out this is done. I've tried ajax, .click(), sending it via post but I keep getting errors

Comment: without seeing your code how can I say where you went wrong,  post your code [ how do you sending the data .]

Comment: a function sentToServer was added to send data via ajax function `sendToServer(data) {
                     $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     data: {
                        arr: JSON.stringify(data)
                     },
                         url: "next.php",
                         success: function(data) {
                             alert(data);
                         }
                     });
        
                 }`

Comment: I you have any other way of sending data I would be happy to see it. I like seeing new ways to do the same process

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and include jquery min js :

```
<div class="my-form">
    <form role="form" method="post">
        <p class="all_fields">



            <div id="commonPart" class="commonPart">
                <label for="author1">Author <span class="author-number"></span></label>            

                <input type="text" name="author" value="" id="author1" />
                <br/>

                <div>
                    <label for="author1">book <span class="author-number"></span></label>      
                    <input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        <button type="button" class="add_author" onclick="AddCustomMOre();">Add More</button>

        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
   <script> function AddCustomMOre(){
   $(".all_fields ").append('<div id="commonPart" class="commonPart"><label for="author1">Author <span class="author-number"></span></label> <input type="text" name="author" value="" id="author1" /> <br/> <div><label for="author1">book <span class="author-number"></span></label>  <input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/></div>   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Remove</a></div>');  
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
<p class="all_fields">

    <button class="add_author">Add Author</button>

  <div class="commonPart">
    <label for="author1">Author <span class="author-number">1</span></label>            
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="author1" value="" id="author1" />
    <br/>
    <button div-id="1" class="add_book">Add book</button>
    <div id="books1">
        <input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>

<script>
    var c=1;
    $(".add_author").on("click",function(){
        c++;
        $(".all_fields").append('<div class="commonPart"><label for="author'+c+'">Author <span class="author-number">'+c+'</span></label><br/><input type="text" name="author'+c+'" value="" id="author'+c+'" /><br/><button class="add_book" div-id="'+c+'">Add book</button><div id="books'+c+'"><input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/></div></div>');
    });
    $(".add_book").on("click",function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("div-id");
        $("#books"+id).append('<input type="text" class="bookName" name="authBook[]"/>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how do I keep the name of the book with the same number as the author so that the book is related to that author

Comment: you need not to do that. you can get those books by selecting $('#books'+author number+' input').each(function(){alert(this.value);})